# How can Bash determine if it is running due to an rsync over ssh?

Tags: ssh, rsync, bashrc

I need my Bash init scripts to be able to distinguish between

- having been invoked like `ssh me@host /some/complicated/operation`, and
- having been invoked like `rsync -e ssh /src me@host:/dest`

In the first case there are many initializations I want to run, but in the second case I will always want to skip those initializations.  What environment or Bash variable can I use to distinguish these cases?

(Note: This is a self-answered question.)

Comment: Try `$SSH_CLIENT`

Comment: @AdamKatz SSH_CLIENT is not enough.  The connecting client for a normal remote command may be identical to the connecting client for an rsync over ssh.  (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 6):

Invoking rsync over ssh as above (with no other connection options) will cause the remote sshd to spawn a subprocess like this (assuming your default shell on the remote host is bash):

```
bash -c rsync --server [-options] [--long-options] ...
```

This shell is the one sourcing your init file and so in your init file you can make use of the shell variable

```
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING
      The command argument to the -c invocation option.
```

like so:

```
if [[ "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING" == rsync\ --server\ * ]]; then return; fi
```

Shells spawned by regular (non-rsync) SSH connections will not match this command and so will behave normally.

Comment: +1.  you can also use a regex match so you don't have to specify the full command line: `[[ "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING" =~ rsync ]]`

Comment: @cas I originally thought of doing that, but unfortunately that would also match a command like `ssh user@host 'cp rsync.conf backups/rsync.conf.$BKPDATE'`.  And in a case like that I might want my init scripts to run, because maybe they mount a directory at `backups` or initialize the value of `BKPDATE`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for a solution to determine if you are running an interactive session or not, this may help:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
  echo "You are in interactive mode
else
  echo "Non-Interactive session"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for.  I also need to distinguish between non-interactive SSH sessions and rsync over SSH:  they're both non-interactive.  (And while I know that you were just giving an example, it's also broken: one should never `echo` anything in a non-interactive session init script.)

Comment: `echo` is just a place holder. Otherwise I am aware of the implications.